# How to re-perform the javascript keyup function automatically when navigating back to the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to keep the javascript `keyup` function result when navigating back to the page?

In my book list page, I have a search option that searches the title available on the page with javascript. Say I type `harr` in the search box, and the **Harry Potter** result appears. If I click the link to the Harry Potter page and come back again to the index page, the keyword `harr` still in there in the search box but it is not displaying the result obviously rather the whole page.

Is there any way that when I come back to the index page and if there is any input in the search box, the `js` will run again with the keyword so that it'll just show the result, not the entire page?

Here is the snippet: As the snippet doesn't support multiple pages, here is the project in [codepen](https://codepen.io/ashonko/project/editor/Awakpw) where I've created dummy pages for the book Harry Potter.

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    var notAvailable = document.getElementById('notAvailable');

    var hasResults = false;
    Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
        const title = book.textContent;
        if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
            hasResults = true;
        } else {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    notAvailable.style.display = hasResults ? 'none' : 'block';
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="search-books">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
         <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
         <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row list-single" id="notAvailable" style="display: none;">
      <div class="col-12">
         <h5>Sorry, the book has not been added yet</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why would you want to do that ? I mean from a user perspective. why would he want to see the filtered results he already did ? why don't you set your FORM's Autocomplete function OFF. ? So, you won't have to worry about such cases ?

Comment: From a learner perspective, it's interesting I guess. @GeorgeBailey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just put this code (in addition to your current code) to the top level of your script. It will be executed as soon as the page loads (technically, as soon as the script loads) and if there is any text in the input field, that text will be used to filter book entries right away.

```js
const term = searchBar.value;

if (term !== '') { // test if the input fields is not empty
  const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
  let notAvailable = document.getElementById('notAvailable');

  let hasResults = false;
  Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
      const title = book.textContent;
      if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
          book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
          hasResults = true;
      } else {
          book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
  });
  notAvailable.style.display = hasResults ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please have a look at this fiddle, because it doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/aq9Laaew/19364/

Comment: You did not put that code which I have written here into that fiddle.

Comment: Wow! It's perfect. Thanks for the lesson. Cheers!